# Commutative Noetherian Banach algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Prove that:

1) Every commutative real unital Noetherian Banach algebra with no zero divisors is isomorphic to the real or complex numbers.

2) Every commutative real unital Noetherian Banach algebra (possibly having zero divisors) is finite-dimensional.

Comment: You might want to mention that you took these statements from wikipedia. Note that 2) is a result attributed to Grauert and Remmert, extended to the noncommutative case by [Sinclair and Tullo](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01344169#page-1).

Comment: If algebra is artinian it is easy to demonstrate 1).

Comment: 1) follows from 2). Recall every quasinilpotent element is a topological zero divisor. Since the algebra is finite-dimensional, it must be a zero divisor by local compactness. So your algebra is semi-simple finite-dimensional. You can conclude with Wedderburn.

Comment: now I see.
thank you very much